# How to correctly interpret discrete structures logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, logic-translation

I am currently in a Discrete Structures class and am stuck on a concept. The question is: Translate these statements into English, where $R(x)$ is “$x$ is a rabbit” and $H(x)$ is “$x$ hops” and the domain consists of all animals.

$$\forall\,x\big(R(x)\wedge H(x)\big)$$

I answered that "All animals are rabbits and hop," which was marked incorrect. Can someone explain where my logic went wrong?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your answer. Do let us know what the "correct" answer was supposed to be.

Comment: I'm going to try to meet with the professor, I will update the questions when I see him. Thanks.

Comment: I hope you don't end up hopping mad $\ddot{\smile}$!

Comment: Update: the previous grader copied and pasted the wrong answer on the answer sheet, so the issue resolved itself. Thanks for the input regardless.

Answer (score 2):

No idea why it was marked wrong. Your translation look fine to me!